# Nginx Proxy for PlayFramework from port to path prefix

Tags: nginx, playframework

I have a Play application listening on a local port :9000.  There are other applications running. 
I would like to server this application at a path like:

`http://myhost/this-play-app  ->  localhost:9000`

So that other apps could be nested at other paths.

I've tried the basic proxy_pass but it doesn't seem to work.

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name myhost;
    # MMC Tool
    # ----------------------------------------------------
    location /this-play-app {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
    }
}
```

The play app seems to forward to the root.  Is there a way to trick the play app to work within the `/this-play-app` path ?
Like `/this-play-app/some-controller` instead of `/some-controller` ?

Thanks

Comment: Framework has to support this. And anyway, it would be much easier to use subdomain e.g. `play-app.example.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using apps in folders isn't comfortable idea - you would need to at least prepare some dedicated config and change it each time when changing the location.

Instead as other suggested you should use subdomains, in this case each app behaves exactly the same as in the root domain and even if you will need/want to change that domain all you'll need will be change in the nginx's config.

Typical nginx's config looks like

```
upstream your_app {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name your-app.domain.com;
    location / {
      proxy_pass  http://your_app;
    }
}
```

Most probably on some VPS or shared hosts you'll need to add the subdomain by some kind of admin's panel - on localhost just need add the subdomain to the `hosts` file.

**Edit** if using subdomain is not possible anyway (pity) you can workaround it anyway by config, in nginx use (as you did in question:

```
...
    location /this-play-app {
        proxy_pass http://your_app;
    }
...
```

and then add this line into your `application.conf` (Play 2.1+)

```
application.context = "/this-play-app"
```

Or this in case of Play 2.4+ ([info](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24#Configuration-changes))

```
play.http.context = "/this-play-app"
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of that.. So much easier!! Thanks for the brain kick!

Comment: I think I love you. I'll try it out tomorrow! Thanks again

Comment: Ah. I got the main page loading on the subdir, but it seems the application was developed in a way that links are constructed manually rather than by Play `@routes`. This Play app was outsourced. I'll stick to port numbers for now, and request they change link references to use `@routes`.

Comment: That's why it's far better to use `@routes` always - even if it requires _more work_ (de facto it doesn't in the regular work)

Comment: Absolutely agree. Unfortunately I wasn't overseeing this development. Having done a lot off Rails I understand this principle, and would've questioned it on day 1. But :) Such is the world of software development.